# Post and receive google map location data to/from external website and android application

Tags: android, sql, google-maps

I'm rather new to android development but I have a little project that I'd like to do and would like to know if it was possible to do.

Basically what I'd like is for an Android app to add location nodes to an external database and also allow the app to read the database and display all of the nodes stored in it.  This allows a user of the app app to add nodes to the database and any other user of this app will display the nodes when the app is launched and vice versa.

Is this possible to achieve? And if so what sort of resources would I need to accomplish this?
I'm guessing I might need to use the Google Map API?

Answer (score 1):

To show locations on a map [use a MapActivity](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). If you need to get the user's location [use the LocamationManager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html).

Comment: Thanks, this has been a great help